# Pycharm gets error "can't find '__main__' module"

Tags: python, pycharm

Whenever I try to run script via Virtualenv in pycharm, i get this error:

```
C:\Users\Costello\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Costello/PycharmProjects/test
C:\Users\Costello\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:/Users/Costello/PycharmProjects/test'
```

Everything works fine via idle, or vs code. 
I figure it must be something with a way that I have setup my pycharm but have no idea what.

edit: this happens whatever I run, even simple print function.

edit: even with choosing regular python intepreteur, same happens just in pycharm

```
C:\Users\Costello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:/Users/Costello/PycharmProjects/test'
```

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: Whatever I run. Even tryed simple print("bla bla")

http://prntscr.com/kn60cu

Comment: How are you running the code? That does not seem like a Python file, it does not end in .py

Comment: It does end in py and it is python file, you can see that it ends as test.py and python icon next to the file.
I figured out whats wrong, submitted the answer. 

thank you folks

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Figured out whats wrong. In the configuration window in pycharm, I had to select proper script path:

[image]

Comment: Script path is misleading (IMHO) as it needs to include the script file too.

Comment: So every time you need to run a new script you create a new configuration? It does not make any sense..

Comment: that was the problem in this paticular case.

Comment: FWIW, here's how I finally solved this problem.  This is my first session with PyCharm, so I'm groping a bit more than I will be a month from now.  I had tried to put a command line parameter in my configuration file, but realized I was putting it in the "Interpreter parameters" filed, not the "parameters" field.  When I cut-and-pasted to move it, I left the opening " in the "Interpreter parameters" field.  Clearing that solved my problem.  I guess PyCharm doesn't validate that field.  Caveat usor.

Comment: @user2399432 They now have a "Current File" option that will run the active file.

Answer (score 16):

In your Pycharm:

1. Select `Run - Edit Configurations`
2. In `Configuration tabs`, select `Module name` in option `Choose target to run` and type your python file's name
3. Click `Apply` and `OK` button

Or the simple way is when you run your code for first time (on a new file) just type keyboard `Alt+Shift+F10` to run and save the configuration. On the second time (after configuration is saved) just type `Alt+F10` to run your code.

Comment: also called 'script path'

Comment: its 'Shift+F10' now for running the code

Answer (score 5):

"Open 'Edit Run/Debug configurations' dialog" (on the top, next to "Run") 
 "Edit Configurations" 
 "script path:" --> select correct script path.

Comment: This worked great, thanks. The path should include the name of the .py file as well. Not just the path which is just a folder.

Answer (score 4):

Go to "Edit Configuration" and only speciy your filename like `filename.py`

Existing path -----> `C:\Users\np4\PycharmProjects\TEST\venv`

Try with this -----> `C:\Users\np4\PycharmProjects\TEST\venv\MultiSites.py`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by removing values from **Interpreter options** field in run/debug configurations. While trying to add an interpreter, I had added the python path to the mentioned field.

After clearing out the field all worked well.

You can find `run/debug configuration` settings in the drop-down left of run icon on top-right of pycharm window.

Answer (score 2):

I recently started working in python and ran across this issue. The way I got around is that in the configuration window:

1. leave the script path empty
2. add the path to the script's directory in the working directory
3. in the parameters, add `$FileName$`

This will automatically pick your file and run it.

Answer (score 1):

In Pycharm (Ubuntu):

1. Create New Project
2. Give Project Name
3. Right Click on bin folder
4. Create New Python File
5. Write Your Code
6. Upper Right Side: Add Configuration
7. Left side: right click on "+" sign
8. Input full file name
9. Home/Downloads/myfile.py as "Script path"
10. python 2.x/3.x as Python Interpreter
11. Click on apply / ok

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when my `cmd` was forced to "End Task" by "Task Manager". My problem solved when I restart my IDE.

Answer (score -1):

add this in you python file

if **name** == '**main**':
app.run(debug=True)